# Calling one command from another

Tags: hubot

I want to do some kind of alias, for example, `hubot status` should call `hubot newrelic me` and `hubot gauges for today`.

I tried to do things like `msg.send "hubot newrelic me", but seems like hubot just ignore the message.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make scripts talk one to another using events.

```
 robot.emit 'event', param

 robot.on 'event', (param) ->
   console.log 'received param', param
```

Here's more information about it: https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read#leanpub-auto-cross-script-communication-with-events